# Слишком большой размер изображений после загрузки на сайт

Tags: php, изображения, загрузка

Всем привет, на днях заметил такую проблему - изображения после загрузки на сайт становятся в 4-5 раз больше чем изначально, к примеру, если картинка была 200кб, то если ее после загрузки на сайт скачать, она становится уже почти 1мб. По этой причине сайт начал тормозить. Эта проблема появилась после модификации обработчика загрузки изображений submit.php - программист добавил в него функцию мультизагрузки изображений. До изменения этого файла таких проблем не было.
Вот ссылка на обработчик в txt формате:
[submit](http://pumpy.one/submit.txt)

Comment: так и обратитесь к этому программисту

Comment: Он не выходит на связь.

Comment: Тогда нанимайте на работу какого-нибудь другого программиста

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Строки 458, 459:

```
imagesavealpha($image, true);
@imagepng( $image, $totalPath );
```

Сохраняется PNG-файл с альфа-каналом. Размер задан на строках 439-442:

```
$imageWidth=imagesx($image);
$imageHeight=imagesy($image); 
$newImageWidth = 700;
$newImageHeight = ($newImageWidth * $imageHeight) / $imageWidth;
```

Размер задан - ширина 700 пикселов по принципу "прокрустово ложе", т.е. маленькие картинки растягиваются до 700 пикселов, большие ужимаются.

PNG - формат менее компактный, чем JPEG. В нем используется сжатие без потери качества. Вот причина того, что много пространства занимается графикой.

Обсудите со своим разработчиком, может быть, вы захотите картинки переложить на какой-нибудь хостинг, если ваш хостинг не справляется.

Вместо imagepng можно использовать imegejpeg: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imagejpeg.php

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Теперь понятно, а возможно эту функцию убрать или изменить чтобы файлы сохранялись в jpeg формате, а не в png? Я про @imagepng - строку 459. И как это сделать?

Comment: Да, вот imagejpeg https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imagejpeg.php Ваш скрипт относительно большой, нужно тестировать, как он будет работать с этим изменением. Лучше действительно попросить того, кто это писал, поменять imagepng на imagejpeg. Или перевести картинки на внешний хостинг, на CDN.

Comment: Заменил @imagepng на imagejpeg и изменил ширину изображений на 600px теперь размер картинок стал даже меньше исходного, что очень хорошо. PNG файлы загружаются, но без прозрачности что не критично. Спасибо вам за помощь.

Comment: Хорошо! Если вас устраивает ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его как принятый, поставив на нем зеленую галочку.